# HIbernate Envers: retrieve snapshots inserted in the same transaction

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

We've got a requirement: log and persist the entity changes in the transaction in terms of diff using Hibernate Envers. We implemented a `RevisionListener`:

```java
public class MyRevisionListener implements EntityTrackingRevisionListener {

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revision) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void entityChanged(Class entityClass,
                              String entityName,
                              Serializable entityId,
                              RevisionType revisionType,
                              Object revisionEntity) {
        int revisionId = ((DefaultRevisionEntity) revisionEntity).getId();
        List<?> revisions = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager)
                .createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(entityClass, false, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().le(revisionId + 1))
                .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
                .setMaxResults(2)
                .getResultList();

        checkArgument(revisions.size() < 3, "Need at most two revisions: %s", revisions);
        checkArgument(revisions.size() > 0, "Need at least one revision: %s", revisions);

        // continue with diff calculation;
    }

}
```

Questions:
1. First assertion: Do I need this checking? Having the above query Is it possible that the result contains more than two items?
2. Second assertion: I assume for every change (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) there's at least one snapshot (or revision). Is that right? If so why do my test cases (with an UPDATE operation) fail randomly due to this assertion failure (meaning there's no snapshot).

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

**UPDATE**
The problem was with Spring Test, context, and bean management (specifically how I obtain `EntityManager`). I accepted the post by @Naros as it answered the first question and gave a hit for the second question :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you cannot do this at query-time using the AuditReader API instead?  I'm concerned that you may run into issues in a concurrent scenario where 2 sessions modify the same entry back to back and you might end up generating your diff incorrectly at transaction commit time.

Comment: What do you mean by query-time? I'm not sure how to do it. Any example or guide? Thanks

Comment: Let me ask this, do you need to just present this _diff_ in a UI or report on an as-needed basis where you have access to the Envers API?  I don't want to suggest a solution where you intend to access it from the database directly.

Comment: I need to persist the diff as part of the transaction.

Comment: Well first of all, Envers allows you to use the `withModifiedFlag=true` option on the `@Audited` annotation to do that.  Again, I don't believe you need to write anything custom here but instead use the AuditReader API to fetch this when you need the diff.  You haven't given me anything to really go on that would suggest otherwise.

Comment: First thanks for your patience. I was aware of `withModifiedFlag` but it's not enough since one column is a big JSON and we're interested in the diff in this column. For the sake of easy auditing, apart from snapshots (saved by Envers) I need to calculate the diff and persist the diff as part of the transaction so that later anyone can easily read changes (or diffs) directly in the DB. Would you please confirm if my assumption is correct and if it's correct why it fails sometimes? Thanks.

Comment: Great that gives me some context to answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need this checking? Having the above query Is it possible that the result contains more than two items?

No, `setMaxResults(2)` will guarantee that the query returns only a maximum of 2 rows; however you'll need to handle the use case where the query returns less-than 2.

> I assume for every change (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) there's at least one snapshot (or revision). Is that right? If so why do my test cases (with an UPDATE operation) fail randomly due to this assertion failure (meaning there's no snapshot).

I wouldn't expect your test case to fail randomly unless you're doing something you shouldn't be.  The audit process with Envers is pretty deterministic, so I would expect it to either fail or succeed consistently.

As to why you aren't getting the expected number of rows, my guess would be either some flush mode configuration is at play that could interfere with Envers audit queries or perhaps you're querying the audit schema amidst saving an entity and its associations such that an expected valid predicate where clause is invalid at that precise moment?

Without seeing your test case, I can only speculate for the most part.  If you can post your test case and entity mappings, I could dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. it helped me figure it out what the issue is. As matter of fact the issue is not with this part of the code, but with Spring Test, context and bean management.